# How to boot windows 8 with ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, uefi

I am new at ubuntu i have a Sony notebook whit pre. Installed windows 8, and ubuntu studio 13.10, and can only boot ubuntu i put up the grub to sda3, and mount the windows 8 partition to boot whit g part, but then I find out that it lays on sda2, when I boot windows 8 it says that it can not load image, and has set it up to an windows boot mange (uefi /dev/sda3), and i don't know what to do to boot windows 8.

Thanks.

Comment: Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode? Once you start booting in one mode you cannot use grub to switch boot modes, so both systems have to be the same to work. Post link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

The boot repair program has successfully been used for these problems.

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-repair-simple-tool-to-repair-frequent-boot-problems.html

Comment: Hi. Again it still will not boot when it can not find the bootmgw.efi, and say can not load image file.